# Adding a template file (phtml) via layout XML?

Tags: magento, layout

I created a template file, called mytemplate.phtml. It is situated in *app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/myfolder/mytemplate.phtml*.

Now I want to add this using layout XML, like this:

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="core/template" template="myfolder/mytemplate.phtml" name="some_name"></block>
</reference>
```

Problem is, the content never shows. I cleared the cache, but it did not help. Do I miss something?

Thanks!

Comment: That should work theoretically, so there is probably an issue somewhere else that you haven’t shown. Empty XML nodes should be closed with `/>` rather than `</node>`, but I think Magento will still process the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Block that you are using should work. As it is not working for you, May be possible you are adding this block on another hnadle in layout xml file.

If you will use default handle it will work for you on every page. As below:

```
<default>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" template="myfolder/mytemplate.phtml" name="some_name" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

You can check applied layout handles for a particular request by the following way:

```
Zend_Debug::dump($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());
```